# URL Rewriting in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I just rebuilt a site that is currently located at

http://domainnamehere.com/v2

The existing site is located at

http://domainnamehere.com/

I need to set up a redirect so that when someone goes to the old site, it redirects to the new site. I did this on the htaccess file:

```
Redirect /index.html http://domainnamehere.com/v2/
```

But this only redirects the homepage, not the rest of the site. I also have another directory that is linked to a separate domain. The above htaccess code redirects http://anotherdomain.com to http://domainnamehere.com/v2. I do not want it to redirect other domain names. THe reason it is redirecting the other domain name is because the files are located in a directory on domainnamehere.com. I hope that makes sense!

If someone goes to http://domainnamehere.com/somethinghere I also want it to redirect to the 404 error page that would be located at http://domainnamehere.com/v2/somethinghere

Basically, I need proper htaccess code for this situation!

Comment: So are you wanting to redirect ALL requests to ALL files in your root directory, but not redirect for the FOLDERS in the root directory? Or is there also certain files you don't want to redirect? If so, you could create a white list or black list. The white list would simply be a list of pages you WANT to redirect, or a black list would be a list of files you DON'T want to redirect.

Comment: yes, that is correct, all requests in the root directory EXCEPT for one folder. Can I exclude a fodler from the rule?

Comment: so yes, a black list is the way to go for that issue, how do I go about that?

Comment: Why don’t you just swap the contents of your document root directory with the contents of your *v2* directory?

Comment: its is complicated, there are a lot of reasons why, but I wont get into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should forward {whatever is after you slash} to /v2/{whatever is after you slash}

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^domainnamehere\.com$
RewriteRule /(.*) domainnamehere\.com/v2/$1
```

EDIT: this is for isapi rewrite, but the syntax is similar if you are using mod_rewrite.

Comment: This led to an error (of course i replaced domainhere with proper domain)

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^domainhere.com$ RewriteRule /(.*) domainhere.com/v2/$1

Comment: thanks for the update, but still no luck:

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: I am confused, since the answer was accepted - did you resolve the issue or do you need more assistance?

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainnamehere\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/v2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note: jfrobishow technically answered this first, this is just a fix.

Edit: Added optional www.